# IOS Preview in landscape with correct zoom

Tags: ios, camera, zooming, landscape, preview

Who can give me an minimal example in IOS 5 or higher

of an app that captures the video of the backside cam with the following requirements:

1. The resolution of the image captured by the camera is 1280x720
2. The preview layer is a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and fills the full screen on both IPhone 5 and 4
3. The orientation of both video and preview is LandScapeRight
4. If I want to zoom the preview, I correctly zoom into the center of my landscape image

I got everything working until 4.). But everytime I try to apply the zoom with

```
viewLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
```

I observe that in landscape orientation the center of the focused image is left below the center of the unzoomed image. That is the problem I am trying to solve. So if I set the scale to 1, 1.3, 1.6 or 2.0 I want to always see the center of my unzoomed image.